# Batch script for loop & nslookup

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, nslookup

I've seen this question posted before, but none of the solutions address my issue.  I'm simply trying to iterate through a text file that contains host names.  When I try the same command (omitting the extra percent signs) from the command line, it will work once or twice then then give the error noted below.  Running it as a batch file, the batch file exits without doing anything. This one has really stumped me.

Here's the code in my batch file:

```
@echo off
set OUTPUTFILE=Results/Results.txt
set lookup=HostNames.txt
FOR /F %%i in (%lookup%) do 
FOR /F "usebackq skip=3 delims=: tokens=2" %j in (`nslookup %i`) 
do @echo %%i %%j >> %OUTPUTFILE%
```

At a command line I get:

> i`) was unexpected at this time.

When I run it at a command line I am taking out the additional percent signs needs when it runs in a batch file.  I'm also using absolute                   paths at the command line, to ensure it this isn't an issue with the environment variables I've set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
set OUTPUTFILE=Results\Results.txt
set lookup=HostNames.txt
FOR /F %%i in (%lookup%) do ( 
 FOR /F "skip=3 delims=: tokens=2" %%j in ('echo(^|nslookup %%i') do @echo %%i %%j >> %OUTPUTFILE%
)
```

Problems:
 `/` is a switch in winbatch; `\` is a directory-level-separator.

`do (` must be on the same physical line as its `for`

`%i` should be `%%i`

`%j` should be `%%j`

I've removed the `usebackq` and changed the quotes from backticks to single-quotes as it's not necessary to use `usebackq` here.

---

(minor fixes added)

The "flashing cursor" is caused by `nslookup` requesting information from the keyboard. Adding `echo(` supplies a newline to terminate `nslookup` and `^|` is an escaped-pipe which directs the output of that `echo` to the input of `nslookup`.

Since my setup differs radically from yours, I can do but primitive verification.

Comment: you forgot to set double percentage here `nslookup %i`

Comment: Thanks npocmaka & Magoo.  This is closer, I think but still doesn't seem to be working.  @Magoo I tried your corrections, now I'm getting the following output when I run the batch file:
`
(FOR /F "skip=3 delims=: tokens=2" %j in ('nslookup HOSTNAME_EDITED') do @echo HOSTNAME_EDITED %j  1>>Results\Results.txt )
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
`

Comment: When I set "nslookup %%i" I get a flashing cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the script, useful and highly configurable. Noice!

Answer (score 2):

@Magoo had the best answer for my needs.  The batch file works as intended once I fixed a major issue: Kids, DON'T name your batch file with a windows internal command name. I had called the batch file "nlookup.bat" which caused MAJOR brain damage; a lesson I'll not soon forget.

Thank you all, this is working well now!

Comment: I had the same issue and was so confused by the output and incapacity to do ctrl+c to stop it.

Comment: You have saved me from major brain damage.

Answer (score 1):

I modified Magoo's answer to output to a CSV file.  It will output two columns "#, Input, Output" where you will have two rows for each successful nslookup call, one with the hostname, and one with the IP. I also modified the delims to delimit on ":" and " " so that the output doesn't have a bunch of extra spaces.  I wanted to contain each query on a single row with columns "Input, Hostname, IP" but I got frustrated so I just added a counter in the loop and outputted it as the first column for each separate query and figured this was good enough.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set me=%~n0
set parent=%~dp0
set outputfile=%parent%nslookup_results.csv
set inputfile=%parent%nslookup_input.txt
@echo #,Input,Output >> %outputfile%
FOR /F %%G in (%inputfile%) do (
 set /a resultcount+=1
 FOR /F "skip=3 tokens=2 delims=: " %%J in ('echo(^|nslookup %%G') do @echo !resultcount!,%%G,%%J >> %outputfile%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
@echo off
set "OUTPUTFILE=Results\Results.txt"
set "lookup=HostNames.txt"
FOR /F %%i in (%lookup%) do  (
    FOR /F "usebackq skip=3 delims=: tokens=2" %%j in (`nslookup %%i`) do (
        @echo %%i %%j >> %OUTPUTFILE%
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks!

I don't think that's the right syntax in ('nslookup %%i')

When I set "nslookup %%i" I get a flashing cursor.