# How to nslookup and write to txt file using a batch script.

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im in the middle of a small programming assignment right now, and am stumped. What needs to be done is->

Create a batch file to perform the following steps ( written the best I can in pseudocode )

```
IF USERDOMAIN==COMPUTERNAME 
THEN
CreateFile cake.txt
cake.txt = %USERNAME% + " " + %COMPUTERNAME% + " " + nslookup(www.disney.com)
```

How far I've gotten on the other hand is so=

```
IF USERDOMAIN == COMPUTERNAME GOTO Text

:Text
echo.>"C:\cake.txt"
rem Saved in C:\cake.txt
echo USERNAME >> cake.txt
echo COMPUTERNAME >> cake.txt
```

I only know C#, and using stackoverflow I have found this similar question:
[Batch script for loop & nslookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950161/batch-script-for-loop-nslookup)

But, the syntax in that question is just of nslookup in general, I dont understand the windows batch syntax at all, I got this far through a couple hours of searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```cmd
@echo off
rem case insensitive string comparison
if /i %USERDOMAIN% == %COMPUTERNAME% (
   rem clear file
   break>"C:\cake.txt"
   rem output all commands in following block to file
   (
      echo %USERNAME%
      echo %COMPUTERNAME%
      nslookup www.disney.com
   ) >> "C:\cake.txt"
)
```

if you want to filter the output of `nslookup` you have to do it differently but as you don't tell about how the output should look like this mabe should be enough.

> I dont understand the windows batch syntax at all

If you would be more specific about your problems it would be possible to explain you the things you didn't get.
A good reference about batch scripting is [the site SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/). Every command is very well explained there and completed by examples.

---

> Why did you use `@echo off`? in the start, and use `echo` later on? Isn't it just a way to output status info of how the code is progressing? The purpose of the `/i` is also unknown to me, and finally, why did you `break` before handling the file? I read that a single `>` is for removing and clearing text, so why would that need a `break` of some sort?

**1.
`@echo off` and `echo`:**

The `@echo off` command is used so that the commands itself are not displayed during the batch processing, consider the following example:

```cmd
@echo off
echo Hello world with echo off!
@echo on
echo Hello world with echo on!
```

In your command prompt it would print something like:

```cmd
Hello world with echo off!

C:\Users\...\Desktop>echo Hello world with echo on!
Hello world with echo on!
```

The `echo` command is just used to output something to the console.

**2.
`if /i`:**

The `/i` will compare the strings case insensitive so that `"ABC" == "abc"` or `"abC" == "AbC"` will be `true`.

**3.
`break` and `>` or `>>`:**

To clear a file you used `echo.>"C:\cake.txt"`. This is not completely wrong but that will save a new line into the file and not clear it as `echo.` means new line. The `break` command will generate no output ([see here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19633987/8051589)), if that will be redirected to a file with `>` the file will be completely empty.
You differ between `>` and `>>` when talking about redirection. A single `>` means overwriting the existing file if it already exists and a double `>>` means append to file or create a new file if it doesn't exists.

Comment: I would suggest, that you consider using `IF /I "%USERDOMAIN%"=="%COMPUTERNAME%" (` instead.

Comment: Okay; I was doing some googling and I sorta understand the echo command. But; the rem command, does that create a file there? Why does it say "rem clear file"

Comment: @Compo: Thank you right... Case insensitive is better here!

Comment: @Matapatapa: `rem` is used to comment, everthing after rem is not interpreted by the command shell.

Comment: Okay; I understand it now, but I still have several questions. Why did you use "@echo off"? in the start, and use echo later on? Isn't it just a way to output status info of how the code is progressing? The purpose of the "/i" is also unknown to me, and finally, why did you break before handling the file? I read that a single ">" is for removing and clearing text, so why would that need a break of some sort?

Comment: @Matapatapa: I extended my answer, maybe now everthing is clear. But as I said [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) is a good reference. Also using commands with `/?` will provide much helpful informations.

Comment: Okay; I just went over it one more time. It all makes sense now. Thanks for the help!